# MATLAB symengine fails on a logical statement

Tags: matlab, logical-operators, symbolic-math, inequality

I want to make matlab agree with the following simple statement:

`(x-a)^b>=0` when `x>0, a>0, b<0, x>a`

In order to do so I write:

```
syms x a b
assume(x>0 & a>0 & b<0 & x>a);
isAlways((x-a)^b>=0,'Unknown','error')
```

And get the following error message:

```
Error using symengine
Cannot prove '0 <= (x - a)^b'.

Error in sym/isAlways (line 38)
Y = mupadmex('symobj::isAlways',X.s,isMath,['"Unknown' p.Unknown '"'],9);
```

Why does MATLAB fail to agree with such an evident statement?

Comment: Stack Overflow has not implemented TeX support. Please write your equations differently, e.g. as code

Comment: Thank you for the respnose. I have been trying many different approaches to assume that are listed here https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html (see Multiple Assumptions section) but the result remains the same.

Comment: I'd suggest asking Mathworks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why but instead of using as assumption `x>a`, use `x-a > 0`. I think MATLAB doesn't "compute" the difference between `x` and `a` and so it doesn't know if `x-a` is greater than `0` or not. So it must already know that `x-a` is greater than `0` when you check the condition.

Comment: this 9.4.0.902940 (R2018a) Update 4

Comment: It really works for me, thank you! If someone knows the reason please report it.